# Flutter - Flame and Internationalization?

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, flame

what is the recommended i18n method for Dart programs without Flutter widgets (Games using Flame package)?

I tried the dart Intl package and the Flutter intl package with the Android Studio plugin but can't get it running properly. I use DeviceLocale to get the locale but want to use proper classes/methods to read the strings in each locale from files (e.g. arb), but I didn't figure out how to do it with the given tools. The Flutter intl package always wants a context for translations which I don't have necessarily in a Flame game. Of course I have a working solution based on a Translation class and Maps, but I expect there should be a common way to do this properly.

Does anyone have examples on how to implement this in a clean way?

Regards,
Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) 1.8.0 version, you should be able to reference string keys without passing the context.

Answer (score 0):

heyy there have you tried this package [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) , by far this is the best i have got when it comes to localizations

Comment: Looks prommissing, I'll try it out. In fact it looks a bit similar to the class I built up up to now to capsultate the Localizations until I find a proper way, only far more advanced. I knew there had to be somebody who solved this problem before me :-) . We'll see...

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing a game and hit a limitation similar to yours. For that I developed a tool that is almost compatible with `flutter gen-l10n` but can handle non Flutter apps as well. If you want to give it a try it is available on pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/land. It also solves some ICU message limitations found in the Flutter provided solution.